# Dynamically reducing Image size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a Fluid grid style of website... And I would like to reduce the size of all images by 75% when below 1280px, 50% at 800, and so on...

Is there at way to do this with the `IMG tag?`

So far I have tried

```
//html
<div style=" <?*php echo $Img_height_and_width)*?> position:relative;">
    <div class="imagediv">
        <img <?php echo $img_info/> />//My image
     </div>
</div>

//css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .imagediv{ 
        width:70% 
     }
     ...
}
```

Although this does work, text wraps around the larger div ... So I see 2 options

- Re-size Img some other way
- Somehow make text ignore the other div when wrapping

[jsfiddle of why my code does not quite work](http://jsfiddle.net/8UA7t/)

Comment: Show us an example using JSFiddle or something similar so we can see what you mean by "text wraps around the larger div"

Comment: what you hv tried *should* work...please provide a jsfiddle for ease! :)

Comment: *Updated* link -> jsfiddle of why my code does not quite work

Answer (score 0):

If you will use an 'div' like a wrapper for 'img', you could control the width of the 'img' with the width of the 'div'.
You need to set up the width of 'img' on `width:100%`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap
it's responsive

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imagediv">
    <img <?php echo $img_info?> class="img-fluid" alt="profile" width="465px" height="400px" />//My image
 </div>
</body>
<html>
```